# Implement Auth0 in http (non-secure mode)

Tags: angular, auth0

I need to create an application with auth0 for a company, but this company has its website in HTTP and it will not change it to HTTPS, even so I need to use Auth0, but at first glance it is not possible, there is some way to avoid the following error ?

[image]

Comment: You might need to explain to them that any kind of authentication over HTTP is pretty much useless in the first place. I'm sorry if that's not the answer you'd like, but as an expert it's your job to explain it to them, instead of trying to hack around it and deliver an insecure solution. Sometimes it's better just to drop the contract if the customer will not listen to reason - otherwise it might bite you back in the future.

Answer (score -3):

Internally, the SDK uses Web Cryptography API to create SHA-256 digest.

According to the spec (via Github issues), Web Cryptography API requires a secure origin, so that accessing Crypto.subtle in a not secure context return undefined.

In most browsers, secure origins are origins that match at least one of the following (scheme, host, port) patterns:

```
(https, *, *)
(wss, *, *)
(*, localhost, *)
(*, 127/8, *)
(*, ::1/128, *)
(file, *, —)
```

If you're running your application from a secure origin, it's possible that your browser doesn't support the Web Crypto API. For a compatibility table, please check https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_subtlecrypto
https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-do-i-get-auth0-spa-js-must-run-on-a-secure-origin

Answer (score -3):

Safari does not encounter this limitation. Chrome and Firefox do, however.